# STM32 UART receive ISR callback

Tags: stm32

I am using the STM32CubeIDE to setup the UART peripheral. I can check 'USART1 global interrupt' checkbox in the NVIC settings tab. But when I save and generate the source files, I can't find any callback being generated.

Do I need to type it in myself? How would I know the prototype of the ISR callback?

Comment: This would be in the header files, if nothing else find the code that would call it.  And again, mention the *specific* STM32 you are working with, as neither the hardware nor the software is that same across all of them.

Comment: In the specific version of the STM32 HAL I'm currently using (STM32F4) there are weak function definitions for `HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback()` and `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(()` among others. I'd imagine that your (unspecified) version has similar ones, which you need to override with your own code.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am using a nucleo board, the nucleo-f103rb. Does that matter for generating the callback method? I'd expect that the callback would be identical regardless the board/microcontroller. In which header file can I find the prototype?

Comment: @brhans Ah that's great. And how can I learn the names for these prototypes other than asking here?

Comment: @bas - try poking around in the source base, or using a search tool on it.  Figuring out how to find things like this yourself is far more useful than someone else running the search to give you the answer, and along the way you'll start to understand the organization of the HAL code.

Comment: You're going to want to rely heavily on a good IDE here, as you will need to search the source for clues, and follow references and declarations back to their respective source or header files.

Comment: Right, so I found these callback definitions in the 'stm32f1xx_hal_uart.h'. So is that how STM development works? Generate stuff via the STM Cube and then grind through the header files to figure out which functions I need? It's fine if that's the case, but I guess I'm looking for 'the way of working'. If there is an easier/better way I'd like to learn that

Comment: Well, you could always resort to Reading The [Fine Manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/72/52/cc/53/05/e3/4c/98/DM00154093.pdf/files/DM00154093.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00154093.pdf) for the STM32F1 HAL Library. Section 2.5.3 on page 40 would have helped in this case.

Comment: @bas - Sort of, except that generally those with experience don't bother with the silly cube thing...  Your *linker* will pull out the parts of the complete HAL that you use and ignore the rest.  Other projects may reject the entire HAL in favor of different solutions against the hardware.

Comment: @brhans I can't even find that document when I google for 'STM32F1 user manual'. Neither did I find it while on st.com. I downloaded a copy from the link you provided. Thanks for that, will have something to do tomorrow evening as well :)

Comment: @ChrisStratton OK, I guess I don't quite fit in that 'experienced' category just yet :). It's good to know that I shouldn't be using cube in the end. I feel I have to for now, otherwise I really don't know where to start. @ all thanks for all the helpful comments